# Python on Jupyter: import cv2

Tags: python, opencv, numpy, anaconda, jupyter

In Jupyter when I try to run python, I can't run many commands because I get an error when I try to opencv.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IloNf.jpg)

Does anyone know how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you missed steps 7 and 8 in the [install instructions](http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_setup/py_setup_in_windows/py_setup_in_windows.html#) - you need to copy cv2.pyd to site-packages.

Answer (score 0):

Before importing a package it must be installed, run anaconda prompt and run the command **conda install opencv**
note:If you have a newer version of anaconda try:conda install --channel https://conda.anaconda.org/menpo opencv3